# pandas - datetime column subtraction datetime strptime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column `creation_date` in my pandas dataframe as type str that has the following format:

```
2020-02-06 11:35:17+00:00
```

I am trying to create a new column in my dataframe titled `days_since_creation`

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

df['days_since_creation'] = date.strptime(df['creation_date'],'%m/%d/%Y') - today
```

My code is not correct and i'm not sure where I am going wrong. any help is much appreciated

Comment: thank you but when I try that I get a TypeError: Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this out and works alright for me, apologies for the error from my comment.

```
df['days_since_creation'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['creation_date']).dt.date - 
                             pd.Timestamp.today().date())
```

Result w just that one sample:

```
               creation_date days_since_creation
0  2020-02-06 11:35:17+00:00           -646 days
```

Edit: if the granularity is important and you want to specify how to handle the timezone information, do something like this instead:

```
df['days_since_creation'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['creation_date']).dt.tz_localize(None) - 
                             pd.Timestamp.today())
```

Result of that:

```
               creation_date        days_since_creation
0  2020-02-06 11:35:17+00:00 -647 days +23:26:51.569694
```

Comment: If I wanted to convert this column to type int is that possible. when I try to use df['days_since_creation'] = ((pd.to_datetime(df['creation_date']).dt.date - 
                             pd.Timestamp.today().date())).astype(int) I get an error TypeError: cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [int32]

Comment: You can do: `df['days_since_creation'] = df['days_since_creation'].dt.days`. Then that will be dtype int64 or int32 depending on machine :)

Comment: There was already a lot going on in the other line so I think it's good to split up a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
df['days_since_creation'] = pd.to_datetime(df['creation_date'])
df['days_since_creation'] = today - df.days_since_creation.dt.date
```

if you want just integer of no of days

```
df['days_since_creation'] = (today - df.days_since_creation.dt.date ).dt.days
```